# Wierd textbox behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Summary:
C# Winforms app
Devexpress controls
input controls are databound to datasets

now the issue is I have atleast 4 different dialogs (out of 200+) where no text input controls will except key stroke input, but they do accept pasting text from clipboard, it's strange very strange.

I have traced many times to see if there is an unhandled event capturing key press or key down, furthermore I know that on one of the dialogs that has some required fields, error handler is triggering and will not let me leave edit mode of the text field.

so far it is only on textedit and memoedit on 4 dialogs.

Has anyone experienced this behavior? not just with devexpress but with any type of text input control. does anyone have any pointers to share to aid me in finding the root cause of this issue

Comment: Just a guess, but it seems like binding validation is kicking in.  Lots of possibilities, but validation could triggering a loop of check-fail-trigger-check again-fail-trigger-etc... I.e. is there any code that reacts to validation and changes the text?